# fb security warning while trying to login with fbgraph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

while trying to login with fb, using graph API, a web page appear showing message.

SECURITY WARNING:Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. in ios fb graph api.

this error occurs not all the time, but half of the time.

How to skip this fb message ?

Comment: Did you read the message? That's not an error.

Comment: yes, agree not an error, but how to escape this message.

Comment: yeah, agree its not an error, but how to escape this message ?

Comment: Has anyone find the answer. How to escape this massage?

Comment: I do have resolved it. Check my answer [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16831606/1309698

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. I hope it will work for you.

Just paste this UIWebViewDelegate method in your FbGraph.m file....

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ])
        self.webView.hidden=TRUE;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change url :

self.redirectUri = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

FBGraph.m to

self.redirectUri = @"https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
and check.