# facebook Security Warning while user has enabled secure login - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am working on an application which uses FB login. For login from faceBook I am using FBGraph and it works fine if users have disabled secure login in their account, but if user enables the secure login then it gives following message..

[image]

Here is my code i used for login

```
self.fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

    [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:)
                         andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];
```

EDIT:

From suggestions from current answers, I have added following code in my FBGraph.m But with this code i am getting token nil.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"\n\n\nrequest.URL.relativeString = %@\n\n\n",request.URL.relativeString);
    if([request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ]||[request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ]||[request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"http://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ])
    {
        [self.webView stopLoading];
        [[self.webView superview] removeFromSuperview];

        //tell our callback function that we're done logging in :)
        if ( (callbackObject != nil) && (callbackSelector != nil) ) {
            [callbackObject performSelector:callbackSelector];
        }

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I have also changed

`self.redirectUri = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";`

To

`self.redirectUri = @"http://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";`

But still no success....

Please tell me the solution for FB Login.....

Thanks...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Facebook's official SDK.

Download it from here - [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads/)

***Facebook*** says

> The Facebook SDK 3.8 for iOS is a minor update that adds XCode 5 and
>   iOS 7 support, stability fixes, automatic permissions refresh and the
>   ability to specify batch request parameters to (FBRequestConnection).

Answer (score 1):

Change url :

```
   self.redirectUri = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
```

FBGraph.m to

```
   self.redirectUri = @"https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
```

and check.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error , but just a security warning from Facebook. And I have resolved it in my application to escape from this.

Check the below method in FbGraph.m file

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ])
         self.webView.hidden=TRUE;
    return YES;
}
```

check if it's currently present in file. If not then go with it.

Comment: but in this case token is nil